# d3 donut chart arc retrieves wrong data

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I have a d3 donut chart with two arcs, the main arc edge retrieves wrong data to `d` object on mouse over. Rest all areas in the arc shows correct data in log.

The colored area has value `70` and the other arc with `30`. The colored main arc edge shows data of the second arc (30).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/betasquirrel/6zn5rno9/16/)

```
// data
var dataset = [{
    color: "#5FC5EA",
    value: 70
}, {
    color: "transparent",
    value: 30
}];

// size
var width = 460, z
height = 300,
radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
.sort(null).value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
});

// thin arc
var arc1 = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(radius - 20)
.outerRadius(radius - 11);

// main arc
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.innerRadius(radius - 16)
.outerRadius(radius - 17);

// set svg
var svg = d3.select("#d3-setup-donut").append("svg")
.attr("class",'donut-chart')
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
.on('mouseout', function() {
    d3.selectAll('.donut-tooltip').style('display','none');
});

// tooltip
var div = d3.select("body")
.append("div") 
.attr("class", "donut-tooltip");

// draw thinner arc
var path = svg.selectAll(".background")
.data(pie([{
    color: "#222427",
    value: 1
}]))
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", "background")
.attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.color;
})
.attr("d", arc1)
.on('click', function(d, i) {
    //
})
.on("mousemove",function(d, i) {
    var mouseVal = d3.mouse(this);
    div.style("display","none");
    div.html(d.data.label+" : "+d.value)
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX-40) + "px")
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-35) + "px")
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .style("display","block");
})
.on("mouseout",function(){
    div.html(" ").style("display","none");
});

// draw main arc
var path = svg.selectAll(".foreground")
.data(pie(dataset))
.enter().append("path")
.attr("class", "foreground")
//.attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
//.attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
.attr("stroke-width", "20")
.attr("stroke","none")
.attr("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.color;
})
.attr("fill", "none")
.attr("d", arc)
.on('click', function(d, i) {
    //
})
.on("mousemove",function(d, i) {
    console.log(d)
    var mouseVal = d3.mouse(this);
    div.style("display","none");
    div.html(d.data.label+" : "+d.value)
    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX-40) + "px")
    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY-35) + "px")
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .style("display","block");
})
.on("mouseout",function(){
    div.html(" ").style("display","none");
});

// draw inner text
svg.append("text")
.text('60%')
.attr("class", "donut-inner-val")
//.attr("x", radius/12 - 30)
//.attr("y", radius/12 - 10);

svg.append("text")
.text('in progress')
.attr("class", "donut-inner-text")
.attr("x", (radius/12) - 35)
.attr("y", (radius/12) + 10);
```

Comment: I'm not following this. The blue arc has `70` as data, and the tooltip shows `70`. Isn't that correct?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado mouseover to the edge of colored arc. It shows 30 instead of 70. That is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is being caused by the `stroke-width` attribute. What happens is this: the stroke width doesn't just add pixels to the sides of the arc, it add pixels to its end as well.

We can see this in the following demo, exaggerating the stroke width and colouring the transparent path (I also changed the opacity, so you can see where each path ends):

```js
// data
var dataset = [{
  color: "#5FC5EA",
  value: 70
}, {
  color: "red",
  value: 30
}];

// size
var width = 460,
  z
height = 300,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null).value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

// thin arc
var arc1 = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 20)
  .outerRadius(radius - 11);

// main arc
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 16)
  .outerRadius(radius - 17);

// set svg
var svg = d3.select("#d3-setup-donut").append("svg")
  .attr("class", 'donut-chart')
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    d3.selectAll('.donut-tooltip').style('display', 'none');
  });

// tooltip
var div = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "donut-tooltip");

// draw thinner arc
var path = svg.selectAll(".background")
  .data(pie([{
    color: "#222427",
    value: 1
  }]))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "background")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.color;
  })
  .attr("d", arc1)
  .on('click', function(d, i) {
    //
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    var mouseVal = d3.mouse(this);
    div.style("display", "none");
    div.html(d.data.label + " : " + d.value)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 40) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 35) + "px")
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("display", "block");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    div.html(" ").style("display", "none");
  });

// draw main arc
var path = svg.selectAll(".foreground")
  .data(pie(dataset))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "foreground")
  //.attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  //.attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
  .attr("stroke-width", (d,i)=>60 - i*10)
  .attr("opacity", (d,i)=> 1 - i*0.2)
  .attr("stroke", "none")
  .attr("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.color;
  })
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .on('click', function(d, i) {
    //
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    var mouseVal = d3.mouse(this);
    div.style("display", "none");
    div.html(d.data.label + " : " + d.value)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 40) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 55) + "px")
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("display", "block");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    div.html(" ").style("display", "none");
  });

// draw inner text
svg.append("text")
  .text('60%')
  .attr("class", "donut-inner-val")
  //.attr("x", radius/12 - 30)
  //.attr("y", radius/12 - 10);

svg.append("text")
  .text('in progress')
  .attr("class", "donut-inner-text")
  .attr("x", (radius / 12) - 35)
  .attr("y", (radius / 12) + 10);
```

```css
$pale-blue: #f6f8fe;
$dark-two:#253644;
$pale-grey: #f0f4f7;
$font-roman:'Helvetica LT W01 Roman';
$font-light:'Helvetica LT W01 Light';
$font-bold:'Helvetica LT W01 Bold';
body {
  background-color:#25333F;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.donut-inner-val{
  text-anchor:middle;
  font-family: $font-light;
  font-size: 24px;
  fill:$pale-blue;
 }
 .donut-inner-text {
  font-family: $font-light;
  font-size: 10px;
  fill:$pale-blue;
 }
 .background {
  z-index:1;
 }
 .foreground {
  z-index:2;
 }
 .foreground, .background {
  cursor:pointer;
 }
  .donut-tooltip{
 line-height: 1;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 background: #ccc;
 border-color:#ccc;
 //opacity:.5;
 color: #333;
 border-radius: 2px;
 font-size:11px;
 position: absolute; 
 text-align: center;  
 height: 28px;   
 opacity:0; 
 z-index:99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="d3-setup-donut" style="margin:30px auto;"></div>
```

As you can see, the red path is overlapping the blue path.

**Solution**: change the inner and outer radii, and paint the paths using `fill`, not `stroke`:

```js
// data
var dataset = [{
  color: "#5FC5EA",
  value: 70
}, {
  color: "transparent",
  value: 30
}];

// size
var width = 460,
  z
height = 300,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null).value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

// thin arc
var arc1 = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 20)
  .outerRadius(radius - 11);

// main arc
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 30)
  .outerRadius(radius);

// set svg
var svg = d3.select("#d3-setup-donut").append("svg")
  .attr("class", 'donut-chart')
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    d3.selectAll('.donut-tooltip').style('display', 'none');
  });

// tooltip
var div = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "donut-tooltip");

// draw thinner arc
var path = svg.selectAll(".background")
  .data(pie([{
    color: "#222427",
    value: 1
  }]))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "background")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.color;
  })
  .attr("d", arc1)
  .on('click', function(d, i) {
    //
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    var mouseVal = d3.mouse(this);
    div.style("display", "none");
    div.html(d.data.label + " : " + d.value)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 40) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 35) + "px")
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("display", "block");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    div.html(" ").style("display", "none");
  });

// draw main arc
var path = svg.selectAll(".foreground")
  .data(pie(dataset))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "foreground")
  //.attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  //.attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
  .attr("stroke-width", "1")
  .attr("stroke", "none")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.color;
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .on('click', function(d, i) {
    //
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    var mouseVal = d3.mouse(this);
    div.style("display", "none");
    div.html(d.data.label + " : " + d.value)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 40) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 55) + "px")
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("display", "block");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    div.html(" ").style("display", "none");
  });

// draw inner text
svg.append("text")
  .text('60%')
  .attr("class", "donut-inner-val")
  //.attr("x", radius/12 - 30)
  //.attr("y", radius/12 - 10);

svg.append("text")
  .text('in progress')
  .attr("class", "donut-inner-text")
  .attr("x", (radius / 12) - 35)
  .attr("y", (radius / 12) + 10);
```

```css
$pale-blue: #f6f8fe;
$dark-two:#253644;
$pale-grey: #f0f4f7;
$font-roman:'Helvetica LT W01 Roman';
$font-light:'Helvetica LT W01 Light';
$font-bold:'Helvetica LT W01 Bold';
body {
  background-color:#25333F;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.donut-inner-val{
  text-anchor:middle;
  font-family: $font-light;
  font-size: 24px;
  fill:$pale-blue;
 }
 .donut-inner-text {
  font-family: $font-light;
  font-size: 10px;
  fill:$pale-blue;
 }
 .background {
  z-index:1;
 }
 .foreground {
  z-index:2;
 }
 .foreground, .background {
  cursor:pointer;
 }
  .donut-tooltip{
 line-height: 1;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 background: #ccc;
 border-color:#ccc;
 //opacity:.5;
 color: #333;
 border-radius: 2px;
 font-size:11px;
 position: absolute; 
 text-align: center;  
 height: 28px;   
 opacity:0; 
 z-index:99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="d3-setup-donut" style="margin:30px auto;"></div>
```

This is the same code, but painting the transparent path as red. Now, you can see that it ends at the correct end angle:

```js
// data
var dataset = [{
  color: "#5FC5EA",
  value: 70
}, {
  color: "red",
  value: 30
}];

// size
var width = 460,
  z
height = 300,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null).value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

// thin arc
var arc1 = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 20)
  .outerRadius(radius - 11);

// main arc
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 30)
  .outerRadius(radius);

// set svg
var svg = d3.select("#d3-setup-donut").append("svg")
  .attr("class", 'donut-chart')
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    d3.selectAll('.donut-tooltip').style('display', 'none');
  });

// tooltip
var div = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "donut-tooltip");

// draw thinner arc
var path = svg.selectAll(".background")
  .data(pie([{
    color: "#222427",
    value: 1
  }]))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "background")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.color;
  })
  .attr("d", arc1)
  .on('click', function(d, i) {
    //
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    var mouseVal = d3.mouse(this);
    div.style("display", "none");
    div.html(d.data.label + " : " + d.value)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 40) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 35) + "px")
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("display", "block");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    div.html(" ").style("display", "none");
  });

// draw main arc
var path = svg.selectAll(".foreground")
  .data(pie(dataset))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "foreground")
  //.attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  //.attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
  .attr("stroke-width", "1")
  .attr("stroke", "none")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.color;
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .on('click', function(d, i) {
    //
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    var mouseVal = d3.mouse(this);
    div.style("display", "none");
    div.html(d.data.label + " : " + d.value)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 40) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 55) + "px")
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("display", "block");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    div.html(" ").style("display", "none");
  });

// draw inner text
svg.append("text")
  .text('60%')
  .attr("class", "donut-inner-val")
  //.attr("x", radius/12 - 30)
  //.attr("y", radius/12 - 10);

svg.append("text")
  .text('in progress')
  .attr("class", "donut-inner-text")
  .attr("x", (radius / 12) - 35)
  .attr("y", (radius / 12) + 10);
```

```css
$pale-blue: #f6f8fe;
$dark-two:#253644;
$pale-grey: #f0f4f7;
$font-roman:'Helvetica LT W01 Roman';
$font-light:'Helvetica LT W01 Light';
$font-bold:'Helvetica LT W01 Bold';
body {
  background-color:#25333F;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.donut-inner-val{
  text-anchor:middle;
  font-family: $font-light;
  font-size: 24px;
  fill:$pale-blue;
 }
 .donut-inner-text {
  font-family: $font-light;
  font-size: 10px;
  fill:$pale-blue;
 }
 .background {
  z-index:1;
 }
 .foreground {
  z-index:2;
 }
 .foreground, .background {
  cursor:pointer;
 }
  .donut-tooltip{
 line-height: 1;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 background: #ccc;
 border-color:#ccc;
 //opacity:.5;
 color: #333;
 border-radius: 2px;
 font-size:11px;
 position: absolute; 
 text-align: center;  
 height: 28px;   
 opacity:0; 
 z-index:99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="d3-setup-donut" style="margin:30px auto;"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for detailed explanation.